# SQL SERVER : find list of records in one select query that are not in another select query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a large table in sql server database. I need to do the following operations and am struggling with the sql to do this.

step 1: get the max number of records

```
SELECT ROW,COLUMN FROM TABLE1 WHERE STAGE = 130.0
```

step 2 : get the min number of records

```
SELECT ROW,COLUMN FROM TABLE1 WHERE STAGE = 120.0
```

How do I get the list of records that are only there in step 1 and not in step 2 ?

I am calling these queries from python using pyodbc. My current solution is to run the two select queries separately, store the results as python sets and then use set operations within python to find the set of records in step 1 that are not present in step 2. While it works, the solution is obviously slow.

Can I speed this up with a single SQL query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use an except clause, it is used in a similar way to a UNION, but will only show results in the first set that are not in the second

```
   SELECT ROW,COLUMN FROM TABLE1 WHERE STAGE = 130.0
    EXCEPT 
    SELECT ROW,COLUMN FROM TABLE1 WHERE STAGE = 120.0
```